# Asp.Net datetime SQL parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql, datetime

I'am selecting some data from SQL table.Table has a column  which type of datetime (SQL type).

Stored procedure is using this

```
 where CONVERT(varchar(10),post_tarihi,105)=@post_tarihi(event_date)
```

I have a method has a parameter which type of string (Asp.net type)

```
 <asp:ControlParameter  ControlID="txtDate" Name="post_tarihi" DefaultValue="13-11-2013"  PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
```

When I execute sp from sql managment studio,returns some results
But when I run asp.net application returns nothing.
Is there a problem about type ?

if you ask "why you used textbox fot date",I used because using datepicker(jquery)

Comment: I think when you passing parameter by asp.net in this case it is converted to empty date and thats why your r not getting any result

Comment: what date format is the datepicker using?  needs to be MM-DD-YYYY to match format-code for 105.

Comment: @BWS format ="DD-MM-YYYY"..But thats not problem.Because as you see I'am converting datetime column as "DD-MM-YYYY"

Comment: And I dont think this problem about format.Because it is returning empty for defaultvalue of parameter(13-11-2013)

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya  I checked asp.net debug.sending parameter as "13-11-2013"..seems any problem asp.net side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem

1- Changed SQL parameter type from varchar to datetime and changed query as

```
CONVERT(date,post_tarihi)= @post_tarihi
```

2- Changed Asp.net parameter type from string to datetime

```
 <asp:ControlParameter  ControlID="txtDate" Name="post_tarihi" DefaultValue="2013-11-13"  PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime"/>
```

3- Changed datetime format "DD-MM-YYYY" to "YYYY-MM-DD"